# How to Convert a Metafile to Image by Drag'n'Droping in a Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop, metafile

I develop a Winform Application with the framlework .NET 3.5 in C#.
I would like to allow the user to drag&drop a picture from Word 2007. Basically the user open the docx, select a picture and drag&drop them to my PictureBox.

I've already done the same process with picture files from my desktop and from Internet pages but I can't go through my problem with my Metafile. I've done few researches but I didn't find any solutions solving my issue.

Here is what I've done on my Drag&Drop event :

```
 private void PictureBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.MetafilePict)){
        Image image = new Metafile((Stream)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.MetafilePict));     
     }
  }
```

I can obtain a stream with this code : (Stream)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.MetafilePict) but I don't know how to convert it into a Metafile or better an Image object.

If you have any idea or solution, I'll be glad to read it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example of Drag n Drop from Word (not for PowerPoint and Excel):

```
    static Metafile GetMetafile(System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject obj)
    {
        var iobj = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject)obj;
        var etc = iobj.EnumFormatEtc(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DATADIR.DATADIR_GET);
        var pceltFetched = new int[1];
        var fmtetc = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FORMATETC[1];
        while (0 == etc.Next(1, fmtetc, pceltFetched) && pceltFetched[0] == 1)
        {
            var et = fmtetc[0];
            var fmt = DataFormats.GetFormat(et.cfFormat);
            if (fmt.Name != "EnhancedMetafile")
    {
                continue;
            }
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STGMEDIUM medium;
            iobj.GetData(ref et, out medium);
            return new Metafile(medium.unionmember, true);
        }
        return null;
    }



private void Panel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {

    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile) & e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.MetafilePict))
    {
                    Metafile meta = GetMetafile(e.Data);
                    Image image = meta;
    }
}
```

After this you can use image.Save to save picture or you can use it on picturebox or other control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call new Metafile(stream) as there is no method .FromStream in [Metafile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.metafile.aspx).

Comment: Yes, that's true. I've try your way but I've got an error in the GDI+. How could I know of which object type is my Stream ?

Comment: Take a look at the MetaFilePict documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.metafilepict.aspx - maybe this is your case. Otherwise, should work...

Answer (score 0):

I'm still digging into he web to try different way to solve my issue.
Hopefully I've found this unanswered thread talking about my problem but without any response :
Get Drag & Drop MS Word image + DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile & MetafilePict :

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=456722

I work around with another io be able to copy floating Image (Image stored in Shape and not InlineShape) with Word 2003 and pasting into my winform. I can't paste the link of the second source (because of my low reputation on this website) but I'll do if someone request.

So apparently there are a common issue with the fact that you cannot access to your Metafile stored in the Clipboard and by Drag&Drop.

I still need to understand how to get my Metafile by Drag&Drop.